# Displaying logs from when calling external commands from a powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

In a powershell module there is a class with the following method (here simplified). It simply calls docker to automatically build an image.

Everything works and the image is correctly built. What I cannot understand is why the logs from docker are not printed in the console (as they do if I call the same docker command directly instead of inside a powershell module).

```
[void] BuildImage() {
    $imageId = ...
    docker build -f ../Dockerfile . -t $imageId
}
```

Comment: if the docker command is an external command a & at the start would be correct in anyway, even if it is not the root cause of the problem. & docker build -f ../Dockerfile . -t $imageId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a [`void` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-7.3#output-in-class-methods), it produces no output. If you want to send output to the [success stream (stdout)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_output_streams?view=powershell-7.3#success-stream), then change the return type to `[string[]]` and use `return`:

```bash
[string[]] BuildImage() {
    $imageId = ...
    return docker build -f ../Dockerfile . -t $imageId
}
```

If instead you're interested in sending the output to the other PowerShell streams, you could try the following example which includes [redirection of errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.3#example-1-redirect-errors-and-output-to-a-file) then checks if the output type was an `ErrorRecord` it sends it to the [error stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_output_streams?view=powershell-7.3#error-stream) otherwise it sends it to the [information stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_output_streams?view=powershell-7.3#information-stream).

```bash
[void] BuildImage() {
    $imageId = ...
    docker build -f ../Dockerfile . -t $imageId 2>&1 | ForEach-Object {
        if($_ -is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]) {
            return Write-Error $_
        }

        Write-Host $_
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately piping to Write-Host doesn't change the result

Comment: @FrancoTiveron try with that update, perhaps its sending output to the stderr, adding `2>&1` might solve the problem